# Why does using an ArrayList prints numbers?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

**Input Data:**

```
(00:00) Pedro Del Mar & Beatsole - Pianophoria (Original Mix)
https://www.beatport.com/track/pianophoria-original-mix/5970941
[Black Hole Recordings]

03:01 New World - Ushio (Original Mix) 
https://www.beatport.com/track/ushio-original-mix/6021871
[Abora Recordings]
```

**PowerShell Code:**

```powershell
$readData = Get-Content "C:\Users\SomeUser\inputData - Alternate - 2.txt"
$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList


function removeBrackets([string]$removeBrackets){


if($removeBrackets.Contains(":") -and ($removeBrackets.IndexOf(":")  -eq 2)){
           $subString = $removeBrackets.Substring(7-1);
           $ArrayList.Add($subString)
          
   
  }
elseif($removeBrackets.Contains(":") -and ($removeBrackets.IndexOf(":")  -eq 3)){ 
         $subString = $removeBrackets.Substring(7+1);
         $ArrayList.Add($subString)
      
     }

}

for($i=0; $i -le $readData.Length; $i++){

     
     removeBrackets($readData[$i])


}

for($a=0; $a -le $ArrayList.Count; $a++){

   Write-Output $ArrayList[$a]
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
Pedro Del Mar & Beatsole - Pianophoria (Original Mix)
New World - Ushio (Original Mix)
```

**Problem:**

I created a script that filters out data from a text file. It removes the HTTP links and times from the tracks. It then adds the string to an Array List

Why does printing the Array List produce the `0,1`? How do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `ArrayList.Add` method always returns the index of the new item that you add:

```powershell
PS > $ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS > $ArrayList.Add('a')
0
PS > $ArrayList.Add('b')
1
PS >
```

You can suppress this output by either casting to `[void]`:

```powershell
PS > $ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS > [void]$ArrayList.Add('a')
PS >
```

or by redirecting the output to `$null`:

```powershell
PS > $ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS > $ArrayList.Add('a') > $null
PS >
```

Answer (score 5):

ArrayList.Add() returns the index at which the value was added. Get rid of this output by redirecting to $null or casting to `[void]`.

```
$ArrayList.Add($subString) > $null
```

or

```
[void]$ArrayList.Add($subString)
```